# how to play a video on browser using servlets and jsp..and the video is stored in local system like D:/video/sample.mp4

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I tried to use video tag but it is not working when the video is not present project location

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <video width="400" controls>
          <source src="D:/video/Sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>

          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For local absolute filepaths you have to write:

```
<source src="file:/d:/video/Sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Comment: It is working when i create a simple HTML page with out IDE. But it is not working in Netbeans  in a simple web application..

Comment: hi satish did you got the solution for this one ?